# Malformed JSON while trying to send event to Alexa Event Gateway

Tags: json, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to make an Alexa Skill for a Motion Sensor. I need to send an Alexa.ChangeReport event to the Alexa Event Gateway but I keep getting a Malformed JSON error.

I used the exact same event format given by Amazon for their ChangeReport in [MotionSensor Interface Documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/device-apis/alexa-motionsensor.html), but they still say Malformed JSON. Just to begin with, I haven't written code to refresh and get updated tokens but instead just making sure my tokens are valid. Any Ideas?

Here's my code:

```
motion_state=get_motion_state_from_iot()
    acc_token = payload['state']['desired']['LWA_Access_Token']
    message_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    current_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + "Z"

    event_data = urllib.parse.urlencode(
    {  
      "event": {
        "header": {
          "namespace": "Alexa",
          "name": "ChangeReport",
          "messageId": message_id,
          "payloadVersion": "3"
        },
        "endpoint": {
          "scope": {
            "type": "BearerToken",
            "token": acc_token
          },
          "endpointId": endpoint_id
        },
        "payload": {
          "change": {
            "cause": {
              "type": "PHYSICAL_INTERACTION"
            },
            "properties": [
              {
                "namespace": "Alexa.MotionSensor",
                "name": "detectionState",
                "value": motion_state,
                "timeOfSample": current_time,
                "uncertaintyInMilliseconds": 0
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "context": {
        "properties": [
          {
            "namespace": "Alexa.EndpointHealth",
            "name": "connectivity",
            "value": {
              "value": "OK"
            },
            "timeOfSample": current_time,
            "uncertaintyInMilliseconds": 0
          }
        ]
      }
    }
    ).encode("utf-8")
    
    url = "https://api.eu.amazonalexa.com/v3/events"
    
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {acc_token}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    
    posting = urllib.request.Request(url, event_data, headers, "POST")

    try:
        with urllib.request.urlopen(posting) as response:
            lwa_tokens = json.loads(response.read().decode("utf-8"))
            return ("Success!")
            
    except HTTPError as http_error:
        return(f"An error occurred: {http_error.read().decode('utf-8')}")
```

and here's the decoded error

```
"An error occurred: {\"header\":{\"namespace\":\"System\",\"name\":\"Exception\",\"messageId\":\"01ca3509-734d-49ba-a89c-40cf93e2c0ae\"},\"payload\":{\"code\":\"INVALID_REQUEST_EXCEPTION\",\"description\":\"The request was malformed.\"}}"
```

Comment: Print `event_data`, its very likely not JSON.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're encountering this issue is that in your code, `event_data` will be of type `bytes`, rather than of type `string`.

While I'm not terribly familiar with `urllib` specifically, I've provided one of my own confirmed working Python samples below which uses the `json` and `requests` packages to send requests to the Alexa Event Gateway to report the status of a lock:

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://api.eu.amazonalexa.com/v3/events"

headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer your_access_token'
}

payload = json.dumps({
  "event": {
    "header": {
      "messageId": "a76c568c-ace3-11ea-a194-6c4008a0da0e",
      "namespace": "Alexa",
      "name": "ChangeReport",
      "payloadVersion": "3"
    },
    "endpoint": {
      "scope": {
        "type": "BearerToken",
        "token": "your_access_token"
      },
      "endpointId": "lock-appliance-001",
      "cookie": {}
    },
    "payload": {
      "change": {
        "cause": {
          "type": "PHYSICAL_INTERACTION"
        },
        "properties": [
          {
            "namespace": "Alexa.LockController",
            "name": "lockState",
            "value": "UNLOCKED",
            "timeOfSample": "2023-09-17T23:29:00.00Z",
            "uncertaintyInMilliseconds": 0
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "context": {
    "properties": []
  }
})

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers = headers, data = payload)

print("Status Code: " + str(response.status_code)) # 202 Accepted
```